# button.setOnClickListener. error

Tags: android, button, android-studio

This is my code:

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform action on click
    }
});
```

This is the `android developers` guide link:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

This is how the editor shows the code:
[image: In android studio 1.0.2]

As you can see, `setOnClickListener` does not work in `android studio`. Does anyone know why?.

Comment: What's the button class that you imported?

Comment: "import android.widget.Button;" the same one as in the docs

Comment: If you hover the mouse over the red text what is the error that is shown?

Comment: @Override is missing

Comment: can not resolve symbol 'setOnClickListener'

Comment: @Override
        public void onClick(View view)

Comment: add @Override and import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has to be in a method, like onCreate.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! you saved the day!

Answer (score -1):

It's all in your code ?
Or part of it?

If your code is complete ? You should
Add your code ,
Inside method oncreate();